# How to install the Ubuntu OS in Orange Pi 4G IoT?

Tags: linux, operating-systems, raspberry-pi, armbian

I have recently buy an Orange Pi 4G IoT and I have installed the Android 6.0 successfully. 
But for my project need I want to install the Ubuntu OS in it.
Can anyone help me.

Previous Work
Download the Ubuntu from the official website.
http://www.orangepi.org/downloadresources/

And By using the Win32 Disk Imageer I have installed the os in the 64 GB Memory card. Plugged the memory card in the orange pi. 
But I am not getting any output on ribbon touch screen and HDMI display.

I have also tried the same.

http://www.orangepi.org/Docs/SDcardinstallation.html

So please guide me or provide me the appropriate link.

Thanks in Advances For Your Time & Help.

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work? I find the documentation non-existent and I am struggling to understand how I can flash the eMMC card with a working Linux-distro.

Answer (score 0):

Normally those IoT devices require custom images to boot. It's usually due to some driver or kernel related issue. Most popular devices have ready-to-go distributions, if you trust the source. You seem to have downloaded the image from the official site, so you may be downloading a distribution version NOT matching your device hw version, this things tend to be tricky.

According to [this thread](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepibbsen/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3888) there's a working Ubuntu 16 image made for your device.

This is the distro's [download link](http://www.orangepi.org/downloadresources/orangepi4G-IOT/2018-12-04/b102afd89243eb51d50588ca8437b625.html). They provide two images: one for emmc booting, the other for sd card booting

Username: root
password: orangepi

You can use the docs you provided with the images referenced here.

You can check the referenced discussion in case you have trouble with your installation, however, there should be no problem.

**Please, note that the link provided is a different distribution version than the one you linked. This version is older, however, if it works will give you an starting point**

Comment: Your link appears to be exactly the same as the one on the page the OP linked to.

Comment: Sadly, this answer does not provide any useful information but it seems to just be a copy-paste from the website. OP asked about more details

Comment: @Orphans sorry it didn't work for you :( I linked an specific version of the distro rather than the main page which links to "latest one" and a discussion about it which the OP did not link at all, so I cold not be aware if he noticed it or not. The discussion, by the way, is currently active, with people claiming having it working on the specific device. I could not get my hands on one since then to try it myself.

Comment: Thanks @DGoiko for taking time to answer. I did follow the thread but it seems that they assume that you already has extensive previous knowledge about it. I will continue to experiment with the board and if I manage to get it to work - I will let you know!