# Orange Pi 4g-IoT Ubuntu installation issues

Tags: ubuntu, sd-card

I just purchased my first Orange pi 4g-IoT board and have downloaded the Ubuntu distro from the official Orangepi.org site (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12ALlxN_EnXquMG4ieMMxP95LksAW-Pn8) . The zip file contains multiple image files 1)boot.img and 2)rootfs.img . I've tried copying those files files separately to my SD card (using Win32DiskImager) but have been unable to boot from SD card.

Can someone offer me some pointers on what I'm doing wrong? Do I have the wrong image?
Thanks

Comment: *"I've tried copying those files files separately t... using Win32DiskImger"* -- That makes no sense. What offsets did you use, or did you copy over the previous image? *"... to my SD card"* -- The link you provided looks like a set of files for Android on eMMC, and not Ubuntu on SD card. If you want to copy an image file to a SD card, then you need one image file for the SD card, not a set of files.

Comment: Take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/1402671/how-to-install-the-ubuntu-os-in-orange-pi-4g-iot

Comment: Thanks sawdust.I checked that post before asking the question because the links on that site are broken.The problem I have is that I can't find an image that I can copy to an SD card . I've tried the stock Ubuntu image but could not get it the board to boot (works fine on a Raspberry pi though) .I'd be thrilled if  anyone can point me to an Ubuntu (or any Linux distro) image that works for an Orange Pi 4g-IoT . Thanks in advance